# Why does Java for-each loop execute methods on all objects in array?

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

I'm a beginner to coding and trying to implement a Java for-each loop for a simple project. The project in question has the classes LibraryMember and Book, and the class Library contains the other two classes as attributes of type ArrayList. I would like to be able to cycle through both arrays to discern which LibraryMembers and which Books are available, and subsequently perform the appropriate actions on them, such as mark Book checked out (unavailable) and increment number of Books checked out by LibraryMember.

```java
public void borrowBook(String name, String title) {
    LibraryMember lm = findMember(name);
    Book b = findBook(title);
    if (lm != null && b != null) {
        for (LibraryMember libMem : libMems) {
            for (Book book : books) {
                if(book.isAvailability() && libMem.getNumBorrowed()<4) {
                    book.setAvailability(false);
                    libMem.addBorrow(libMem);
                    System.out.println(title + " has been borrowed by " + name);
                    break;
                } else if(!book.isAvailability()) System.out.println(title + " is unavailable.");
                else System.out.println(name + " has too many books.");
            }
        }
    } else if(lm==null) System.out.println(name + " could not be found.");
    else System.out.println(title + " could not be found.");
}
```

When the code runs, the methods act upon each object in the array. I know this is because when the initial condition `if (lm != null && b != null)` is satisfied, the for-each loop continues to cycle through every single member of the array and the methods are executed.

Could someone please tell me why this is? Why doesn't the code act only upon the objects which meet the conditions outlined before the loop? i.e. `if (lm != null && b != null)` and `if(book.isAvailability() && libMem.getNumBorrowed()<4)`. How would I fix this?

Comment: could you further clarify what you mean? It is a bit hard to understand what you hope to achieve

Comment: In other words please show us code which reproduces the problem.  What result do you want to see instead of the current result.

Comment: Why loop through all books when I suspect that `Book b = findBook(title);` is the book you want to process - no?

Comment: Other than checking them for null, you never use `lm` or `b`.

Comment: Why would there be any particular relationship between `lm` and any particular element of `libMems`, just from this code alone?  What part of the for loop checks anything about `libMem`?

Answer (score 0):

You have two `for` loops and you are only breaking out of the `books` one, and the `libMems` loop continues.

```
for (LibraryMember libMem : libMems) {
    for (Book book : books) {
        if( ... ) {
            ...
            break;
        }
```

The simplest way to solve this is to label your main loop and use that label to `break` out of the processing.

Here is added a lable called `checkBorrowLoop`, adding the label is done with the name and a colon `:` then using that name as a part of the break statement.

```
checkBorrowLoop:
for (LibraryMember libMem : libMems) {
    for (Book book : books) {
        if( ... ) {
            ...
            break checkBorrowLoop;
        }
```

*** A small comment on the logic: You should test for `libMem.getNumBorrowed()>=4` and `!book.isAvailability()` before doing any other processing, as there is no point in doing any checks if either of these are true.

Answer (score 0):

The for-each loop does what it is supposed to do: it loops over all members of a collection.

From the code you provided I think you don't need to loop at all since you already have references to the `LibraryMember` and the `Book`:

```
public void borrowBook(String name, String title) {
    LibraryMember lm = findMember(name);
    Book b = findBook(title);
    if (lm != null && b != null) {
        if (b.isAvailability() && lm.getNumBorrowed()<4) {
            b.setAvailability(false);
            lm.addBorrow(lm); // this line looks suspicious!!
            System.out.println(title + " has been borrowed by " + name);
        } else if (!book.isAvailability()) {
            System.out.println(title + " is unavailable.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(name + " has too many books.");
        }
    } else if (lm==null) {
        System.out.println(name + " could not be found.");
    } else {
        System.out.println(title + " could not be found.");
    }
}
```

Note that the line `lm.addBorrow(lm);` (in your original source `libMem.addBorrow(libMem);`) looks suspicious: why would a library member borrow itself?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this code works.